# How can I count the number of transitions from one state to another in python?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe. I want to create a column that gives me the number of transitions between these states.

```
-------
Id     Mode  
G18   Start   
G18   None    
G18   Start   
G18   Start   
G18   Cool    
...

G50   Mod Cool  
G50  Mod Cool   
G50   Mod Cool  
G50   Mod Cool  
G50   Mod Cool
```

I created a column by shifting the values:

```
Id    Mode     trans
G18   Start    Heat
G18   Heat     Start
G18   Start    Start
G18   Start    Cool
G18   Cool     Cool
....
G50   ModCool   ModCool
G50   ModCool   ModCool
G50   ModCool   ModCool
G50   ModCool   ModCool
G50   ModCool   ModCool
```

I written code where i get the counts in the form of dictionary:

```
groups = new.groupby(['Mode', 'trans'])
counts = {i[0]:(len(i[1]) if i[0][0] != i[0][1] else 0) for i in groups}
#counts = {i[0]:len(i[1]) for i in groups} # count (Start,Start)
counts
```

This gives me result in dictionary since i used dictionary in the code.

```
{Start,Start:0
Start,Heat:1
Start,Cool:2}
```

But i want to create a column "count" which will only give me the number of transitions between these mode for each id. Can someone help ?

Comment: The question is pretty unclear. Please present your question in form of Input  and expected output clearly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name of your DataFrame is `df`. If I understand you correctly, a transition occurs if, for a given row, the value of `df.Mode` is different from the shifted value. So you can add a Boolean column indicating the transitions:

```py
df['transition'] = (df.Mode != df.trans)
```

Then you can get the overall number of transitions by summing over this column:

```py
sum(df.transition)
```

Or, to add the cumulative numbers of transitions as a new column:

```py
df['count'] = df.transition.cumsum()
```

To get the numbers for each `Id`, you can do a `groupby`:

```py
df.groupby('Id').sum()
```